# How to prevent block in the dynamic layout from jumping up

Tags: html, css

I need to fix behavior of the [layout](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYMvoL) when changing height of the previous block also changes the position of the next.

In my example, red block (`.jumper`) is jumping up when the 1st element in the 2nd row is "hovered". But I need red block to stand still on its position. Like in [this case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVpqWg) where there was added one element to the second row.

How to do that?

Why in the second case height of the container (`main`) haven't been changed?

Comment: The issue lies in this style applied upon hover `margin: 0 0 -20% 0;` that you apply because you increase the size of your item by 20%. The thing is that the percentage of the margin is relative to the item parent and not the item itself.

You don't have this problem when there is more than one item on the same line because the other items keep their parent height stable.

Comment: Are there ways to force parent's height stability? Like adding empty last element with (`visibility: hidden`) but better.

Answer (score 1):

It's because on hover you add a margin of -20%. If you want to have the same thing then either add another of those pictures, add a margin of 20% on the text div or the best solution:

Change the `margin: 0 0 20% 0` in the hover to `padding` with the same values

Comment: Padding changes height of rows. They start jumping. I need top rows overlaps bottom rows.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it! :)

Just make the following changes to your code:

```
.zaglushka table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.zaglushka:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

I knew there was something weird with the `scale` transformation causing content displacement, it was because of the table that was getting shown/hidden.

I think this solution should do it.

Comment: Ok. But `table` should not be `absolute`, cause I don't want to take it out from the parent drawing context (borders, margins, paddings).